# change a number key in from array php

Tags: php, arrays

How can I change the numbers 0,1,2,3... to another numbers from another array? I have tried many examples from stackoverflow but nothing helps, or I am making a mistake.

Any help is appreciated.

```
$arr = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    600 => 143,
    700 => 153,
    800 => 159,
    900 => 193,
    1000 => 203,
    1100 => 228,
    1200 => 239,
    1300 => 249,
    1400 => 259,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    600 => 152,
    700 => 163,
    800 => 195,
    900 => 205,
    1000 => 216,
    1100 => 244,
    1200 => 255,
    1300 => 279,
    1400 => 291,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    600 => 159,
    700 => 194,
    800 => 206,
    900 => 217,
    1000 => 229,
    1100 => 259,
    1200 => 285,
    1300 => 298,
    1400 => 311,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    600 => 191,
    700 => 204,
    800 => 217,
    900 => 230,
    1000 => 242,
    1100 => 288,
    1200 => 302,
    1300 => 317,
    1400 => 331,
  )
);
```

Comment: It is unclear from question what output you need?

Comment: how to change 0,1,2,3.... to another numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have two arrays - one with data (the array from the question) and the second with keys

```
$keys = [ 101,102, 103,..];
```

you can make new arrray by function [**array_combine**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
$new = array_combine($keys, $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign to new and unset  the old

```
 $arr['my_new_key' ] = $arr[ 'my_old_key'];
 unset($arr[ 'my_old_key']);
```

in your case you  could use

```
 $arr[1000 ] = $arr[ 0];
 unset($arr[ 0]);
```